# Resize newly added child into parent in JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, layout, responsive, autosize

Good night, I've run into a problem where I have an application form that I created, the main Stage has buttons to load different fxml into the app, which then are added into a secondary anchorPane, the problem is that these newly added child anchorPanes are not auto-resizing, even after playing around with the Layout Constrains.

I'm using Java 8 and IntelliJ / SceneBuilder

Main Stage Controller: 
[main_stage_controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qEro.png)

App running in default size: 
[app_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yYlD.png)

App after resizing: 
[app_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWcHD.png)

I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following lines to the child FXML loaded pane fixed it:

```
AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"
```

Now the app resizes and centers the newly loaded anchorPanes.

Comment: SceneBuilder treated the fxml as standalone scenes, not children anchors. hard-coding the layout constraint doesn't seem to cause any problems in the app nor the editor.